# my php code in localhost work correctly but in host dont work

Tags: php, cookies, header

hi my code in localhost work correctly but in host not work ,i think setcookie function dont work 
my code in localhost work correctly but in host not work ,i think setcookie function dont work

```
<body>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['txt_name'])&&isset($_POST['txt_password'])){
include '../config.php';
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$db_name,$db_password,$db_database);
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE      admin_username='{$_POST['txt_name']}' AND admin_password='{$_POST['txt_password']}'");
$i=0;
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>=1){
    setcookie('login',"true",time() + 3600);
    setcookie('username',$row['admin_username'],time() + 3600);
    setcookie('password',$row['admin_password'],time() + 3600);
    header('Location: index.php');
    echo $_COOKIE["username"];
}
}
else
{
if(isset($_COOKIE['login'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
<fieldset>
<legend>
<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
login
</legend>
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="input_section">
<div class="input_group">
<input type="text" name="txt_name" placeholder="نام کاربری">
</div>
<div class="input_group">
<input type="text" name="txt_password" placeholder="کلمه عبور">
</div>
<div class="input_group">
<input type="submit" value="ورود">
</div>
</div>
</form>
</fieldset>
<?php 
}
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check error log file in your host for possible solutions if dubious please post contents of the same here.
2. Make sure you are running compatible php version